# Wordpress - Different 'posts-per-page' for paginated pages

Tags: wordpress

Does anyone know how I can set different posts_per_pages for paginated pages.

For example:

Homepage = Posts per page 20
Homepage page 2 - 5 = Posts per page 10

The query I am using
    $wp_query->query(array(
            'paged'             => $paged,
            'post_type'         => 'cpt_operator',
            'category__in' => array(12,22411),
            'orderby'=>'menu_order',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'post__not_in' => array($test)
        ));

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display post 20~30 on page 2 you will need to calculate the offset

```
function custom_posts_per_page( $query ) {
    if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && (int) get_query_var('paged', 1) >= 2 ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '10' );
        $query->set( 'offset',  ((int) get_query_var('paged') - 2) * 10 + 20);
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_posts_per_page' );
```

10 : number of posts per page on page 2+

20 : number of posts on homepage

Comment: I forgot a semi-colon at first but it's ok now

Comment: i thought it was that too but still getting error at line 9

Comment: hmm, this seems to just revert to using the default wordpress option. here is my query 
$wp_query->query(array(
     'paged'    => $paged,
     'post_type'   => 'cpt_operator',
     'category__in' => array(12,22411),
     'orderby'=>'menu_order',
     'order' => 'ASC',
     'post__not_in' => array($test)
    ));

Comment: Well now you have to set posts_per_page to 20 in wordpress administration. Or use another function to change posts_per_pages to 20 on homepage only.

And a last tip : you can also test the post_type, maybe you don't want to modify the pagination on all archive, on line 2 add :  '&& is_post_type_archive( 'YOUR_POST_TYPE' )